# JPA Spring Data native query and sub entity initialization

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following entity:

```
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Task implements Serializable, TextCard {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

....
}
```

and I have the following Spring Data Repository method with native query:

```
@Query(value = "select distinct t.*, u.* from tasks t " +
            "join locations l2 on t.location_parent_path <@ l2.parent_path " +
            "join categories c2 on t.category_parent_path <@ c2.parent_path " +
            "left join task_applications ta on ta.task_id = t.id " +
            "join users u on t.user_id = u.id " +
            "where l2.id in :locationIds and c2.id in :categoryIds and t.status = :status and t.user_id not in :excludeTaskUserIds and (ta.user_id not in (:excludeTaskUserIds) or ta.user_id is null)",
            countQuery = "select count(distinct t.*) from tasks t " +
                    "join locations l2 on t.location_parent_path <@ l2.parent_path " +
                    "join categories c2 on t.category_parent_path <@ c2.parent_path " +
                    "left join task_applications ta on ta.task_id = t.id " +
                    "where l2.id in :locationIds and c2.id in :categoryIds and t.status = :status and t.user_id not in :excludeTaskUserIds and (ta.user_id not in (:excludeTaskUserIds) or ta.user_id is null)",
            nativeQuery = true)
Page<Task> findByLocationIdsAndCategoryIds(@Param("locationIds") Set<Long> locationIds, @Param("categoryIds") Set<Long> categoryIds, @Param("status") String status, @Param("excludeTaskUserIds") Set<Long> excludeTaskUserIds, Pageable pageable);
```

As the result of this method execution, I'd like to have Task page object where each Task will be pre initialized with appropriate User.

As you may see, in order to achive it, I added the following `join users u on t.user_id = u.id` but it didn't help and `Task.user` is not initialized.

What am I doing wrong and how to achive it?

Comment: If you use JPQL, then you can use `join fetch`. For native query I think you should use custom repository and select every column explicitly.
Join fetch - https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-join-types#fetch

Comment: You select t.* but u without star. Does this yield all columns of user?

Comment: @RobertNiestroj good point, thank you. I added u.* but unfortunately it didn't help